# DRUPAL 8 - module Views database connector

Tags: drupal-7, view

I need for my drupal 8 installation to connect a second database for a view.
I install the module views_database_connector (january 2015 release)
I connect with the setting.

but nothing works, i don't see my database with view.

my settings...

```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'first base',
  'username' => 'first base',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$databases['external']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'second_base',
  'username' => 'second_base',
  'password' => 'yyyyyy',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
   'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Does this module need a patch, and how to apply ??

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create multiple database connection in setting file :

use `\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('external');` to get current active connection.

Comment: you talk about the settings.php file ?